# Clonezilla and multiple Activation for Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, clonezilla, licensing

We have a large desktop deployment (approximately 2000 PCs) coming and I'm in charge in structuring the best possible manner to have the PCs installed and staged before them out to multiple geographical sites. We have already purchased group license for both Windows 7 and Office 2010. The method of deployment is clonezilla multicast from a clonezilla SE. The problem here is Windows 7 seems be installed and imaged successfully but unfortunately Office 2010 needs to be reactivated by each and every PC.

Is there at all a way/method that I could employ to have it activated by at least the first time a PC boots up?

Answer (score 2):

In your Microsoft license portal, you should have an option to use KMS keys. KMS is the [Microsoft Key Management Service](http://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx), and is the proper method of activating/licensing systems deployed in the manner you're planning.

[Here's a tutorial on setting up a KMS host server.](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000582.htm)

Comment: Right, lemme try that one first .. will come back pronto! .. thanx ewwhite!

Comment: Good luck. It's not too difficult a process.

Comment: Right, I just found out that KMS is not the conducive way of deploying because I've been told by Microsoft representative that the PCs needed to be periodically checked via the KMS server every now and then .. then he proposed the VAMT way .. which I'm currently studying ... please if anyone ever had VAMT experience mind sharing it here?